# Ignite off-heap memory consumption

Tags: ignite

Is there a way to know how much off-heap memory will each cache record take? My cache is:

```
IgniteCache<String, byte[]>
```

Each key is around 24-26 symbols and value is 12 bytes. After putting 40000 records off-heap usage grew by 8MB, which is around 210 bytes for each record. Page size is configured as 1KB, metrics show that page fill factor is around 0.97-1.0. Assuming there is not backups

Is there anywhere to read about how  each record is stored in off-heap to understand where those 210 bytes come from? Queries are disabled. Or what could possible cause such consumption?

Comment: There's a lot of metadata pre-allocation. What happens when you have 10 and 100x as much entries?

Comment: @alamar  It seems to grow at consistent rate, at around 300 millions entries it takes up to 80GB

Comment: Is it a single-node deployment or do you have multiple nodes? Do you have backups configured?

Comment: @alamar It is single node and there is not backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/capacity-planning it's exactly about the 200 bytes overhead for an entry, so I think it's kind of expected.

Comment: That's insane, i'be been on this page for hours yesterday and couldn't notice this thing. Thank you a lot